# CheckBox ToolTip Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, so I need some help here. I have a table AgileFactors in my database that has the following fields: AgileFactorID, Name and Description. I am using a checkboxlist to bind the Name as the DataTextField, and the AgileFactorID as the DataValueField. What I would like to do is use the Description field from the db as the tooltip on hover for the info icon which I am displaying next to each checkbox. Please have a look at my code below. At the moment, I am passing in a long string within the span tags, which is pointless. Could anyone help me make sure that the tooltip is retrieved from the db? Many thanks in advance!

```
"SELECT Name, AgileFactorID, Description FROM AgileFactors"

agile_factors.DataSource = ds2;
agile_factors.DataTextField = "Name";
agile_factors.DataValueField = "AgileFactorID";
agile_factors.DataBind();


protected void agilefactors_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var checkBox = sender as CheckBoxList;
    if (checkBox != null)
    {

        foreach (ListItem listItem in checkBox.Items)
        {

            listItem.Text = string.Format("{0} <span class='link'><a href='javascript: void(0)'><font face='verdana,arial,helvetica' size='2'><img src='{1}' Height='15' Width='15' /></font><span><b>Project Duration:</b><br/>Ideally, the project should be close to 6 months: much shorter means less iterations, and much longer tends towards long term planning.</span></a></span>", listItem.Text, GetImageFor(listItem.Text));

        }
    }
}

private string GetImageFor(string text)
{

    // return image url for check box based on text. 
    switch (text)
    {
        case "Project Duration": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Customer Involvement": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Acceptance of Change": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Team Size": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Skill of Team": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Organisational and Reporting Structure": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Process": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Documentation Requirements": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Layout of Workspace": return "images/iicon.gif";
        case "Empowered Team": return "images/iicon.gif";
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as you have a function to GetImageFor, create another function to "GetTooltip".
Pull the tooltip like you did the other fields and assign it to the tooltip property.

**Edit**

You really have all the code, all you have to do is do it.  I wont do the database side for you because you yourself can do that and you've demonstrated that here.

But to add tooltips here you go:

```
 int i = 0;

            foreach(ListItem l in this.CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                i++;
                l.Attributes["title"] = "Tooltip " + i.ToString();
            }
```

Here is a screen shot of the result.
[image]

Comment: If really need your help on this one. I think that using this method is the way to go. I honestly don't know how to get it reading the description from the db though..Could you please show me?

Answer (score 0):

Format as you need, but here you go - one way

```
protected void agilefactors_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var checkBox = sender as CheckBoxList; 
    if (checkBox != null) 
    { 
        foreach (ListItem listItem in checkBox.Items) 
        {                
            listItem.Text = string.Format("{0} <span class='link'><a href='javascript: void(0)'><font face='verdana,arial,helvetica' size='2'><img src='{1}' Height='15' Width='15' alt='{2}' /></font><span><b>Project Duration:</b><br/>Ideally, the project should be close to 6 months: much shorter means less iterations, and much longer tends towards long term planning.</span></a></span>", listItem.Text, GetImageFor(listItem.Text), GetToolTip(listItem.Value));
        } 
    } 
}

private string GetToolTip(string value)
{
    var x = (from y in ds2.AsEnumerable()
             where y["AgileFactorID"] == value
             select y["description"]).FirstOrDefault();

    return x.ToString();
}
```

You're going to need to fix up what you have, but this should help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use the properties of the listitem class and assign the title attribute ?

Comment: For sure - but I was trying to stick with what he had and not rewrite in case he needs that text in a link still, etc.